# Get bundle values in Android

Tags: java, android, bundle

I'm still really confused why I'm having error getting values from the bundle of my main activity.

So, here's my code snippet:

**Level1.class**

```
Chronometer chrono;
chrono = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
chrono.start();

long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chrono.getBase();
int hours = (int) (timeElapsed / 3600000);
int minutes = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
int seconds = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000) / 1000;

Intent lvl1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Finish.class);    
Bundle time1 = new Bundle();
time1.putInt("hour1", hours);
time1.putInt("minutes1", minutes);
time1.putInt("seconds1", seconds);

lvl1.putExtras(time1);
```

and my **Finish.class**: (inside the onCreate method)

```
TextView Set1;

Set1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.time1);

Bundle time1 = getIntent().getExtras();
int hrs = time1.getInt("hour1");
int min = time1.getInt("minutes1"); 
int sec = time1.getInt("seconds1");


Set1.setText(hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
```

Could anyone tell me why I'm having errors?

**Note:** ERROR in line 30, which is the `int hrs = time1.getInt("hour1");`.

LOGCAT:

```
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathattack/com.example.mathattack.Finish}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.example.mathattack.Finish.onCreate(Finish.java:30)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-20 01:54:10.461: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is the error? Post logcat

Comment: what is the error? post the stacktrace?

Comment: Where is the start activity statement in Level1?

Comment: can you show, the startactivity method you are using to start the Finish activity?

Comment: @MartinCazares .. Here it is: Intent finish = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Finish.class); startActivity(finish); It is placed in some if statements if the user answers the question correctly.

Comment: Then thats the issue, you need to pass the intent that has the bundle in order to avoid the nullpointer exception, in the example you just mentioned you will get a crash, because that intent do not contain any extras information, that's why im asking for the startactivity method, to make sure the intent passed on that method actually contains extras...

Comment: Then, I need to put the whole code of the Chronometer where the startActivity is located?

Comment: @MartinCazares this makes my chronometer not running.

Comment: nono, all you need to do, is to make sure that, either you are actually sending extras in your intent all the time OR put a null check in your Finish activity, see, Extras are linked to the intent that starts the activity, that intent is the very same you are getting in Finish when you call "getIntent", so if the intent you are passing DO NOT have extras, bang you just got a nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code and put break points where you get your bundle from your intent to check the value in the bundle. Without doing that your guess is as good as ours.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. What do you mean by break points? Sorry, I'm not so fluent in english.

Comment: that nullpointerexception in your logcat dump is what you would be able to check for using debugging and breakpoints. if you go into eclipse and click on the left of the line numbers on your screen you will drop break points. the little bug at the top of eclipse will start your app in debug mode. When your code runs across the point where the breakpoint is you will be able to check all the values of variables at that point using the debug tools built into eclipse

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `putExtras` (emphasis mine):

> Add a set of extended data to the intent. **The keys must include a package prefix**, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Use `Intent.putExtra("hour1", hours);` instead.

Comment: you mean, lvl1.putExtra("hour1", hours); lvl1.putExtra("minutes1", minutes); lvl1.putExtra("seconds1", seconds); << Like this?

Comment: I change what you said and remain others as is. Am I doing right?